# Kill network connections in WiFi on Android

Tags: java, android, networking, arp

I want to do follwing: My app should be able to kill the internet connection of a specific network device.
I already thought about a library or something like that, but jpcap didnt work for me. Maybe its the wrong one?
Maybe I dont need a library for that, I dont know. But if so, where to start coding? Any keywords for how to beginn?

There are already apps like KillWiFi, so its possible.
I also tried an old version of "arpspoof" but i got the PIE Error on that script/program.
Any ideas how I could do that?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, network wise, there can be different possibilities:

_ First one:
Having access to the end devices and kill the connection directly on them. On windows in can be kill + pid (using netstat etc.).
Practically speaking I doubt you will have access to end users' devices.

_ Second one:
Your device act as a network gateway. Typically a router/firewall/wifi"hotspot".
All the traffic will be passing through the device.
A connection table will be held and then it will be easy to kill any session from here. Most of the device by default doesn't send a TCP reset (if it's TCP we are talking about) so they won't know the TCP connection has been dropped.
Not sure how the syntax is with Java or even if this is possible, but logically you should be able to kill a socket and end any tcp connection for eg. initiate by the device in itself.

Hope this help